# find out the value of $\dfrac {x^2}{9}+\dfrac {y^2}{25}+\dfrac {z^2}{16}$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

If $(x-3)^2+(y-5)^2+(z-4)^2=0$,then find out the value of $$\dfrac {x^2}{9}+\dfrac {y^2}{25}+\dfrac {z^2}{16}$$

just give hint to start solution.

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ assumed to be real or complex? (Or indeterminate? No, you ask for a value) The square of a real number is $> 0$ unless it is zero.

Comment: Got it answer will be 3

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** What values does the function $x^2$ acquire(positive/negarive)? What is the solution of the equation $x^2=0$?

Can you find the solution of the equation $x^2+y^2=0$?

Now, what can you say about the equation $(x-3)^2+(y-5)^2+(z-4)^2=0
$? Can you find the values of $x,y,z?$

Comment: so x=3,y=5,z=4 isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the equation leads to : 
$$(x-3)^2=(y-5)^2=(z-4)^2=0$$

Comment: okay this question was asked in today's exam and i left it unsolved

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Assuming real solutions, there is only one possibility for values of $x, y$ and $z$. Then put in the corresponding values in the 2nd expression. If they are complex then there are infinite values.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $(x-3)^3\geq0,(y-5)^2\geq0,(z-4)^2\geq0$.